# Difference of const and non-const Reference C++

Tags: c++, reference, constants, lvalue, rvalue

```
const int& dummy = 5;
```

The code snippet above compiles without any errors / warnings using the `g++ Compiler`. Conversely using the code snippet

```
int& dummy = 5;
```

produces the following error code:

`invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’ int& dummy = 5;`

Since the reference type from c++ is a lvalue reference I find it surprising that it is possible to assign an rvalue to it if is declared as const. Why?

Comment: What is it you find surprising?

Comment: [*GotW #88: A Candidate For the “Most Important `const`”*](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe since the reference type from c++ is an `lvalue reference` I find surprising that it is possible to assign an `rvalue` to it if is declared as `const`

Comment: counter question: what would you expect to happen in the second case when you write `dummy = 7` (somewhere after the definiton) ?

Comment: SebTu: you forgot `int && dummy = 5;` in your tests

Comment: Not sure what is the question. State a better question and we will find a dupe for it.

Comment: Because that's what the language standard says. By the way you cannot assign to a reference, you can only initialize one.

Comment: You have presumably written (or seen) a function with an argument like `foo(const int &bar)` before... and it has been able to compile when you say `foo(5)`... so does it not seem logical that a `const int &` can be initialized with a literal?